# PHPでcsvダウンロード際に文字化けする現象

Tags: php

csvファイルに記載されているデータを画面に表示し、
それをcsvとして出力するという課題に取り組んでいます。

文字化けを回避するよう記述しているつもりが、なかなかうまくいかず
文字化けしてしまいます。

どなたか教えてください。

【元のcsvファイル】※仮のデータ
"tanaka",5000
"yoshida",1000
"suzuki",400

【ブラウザに表示したいデータ】
社員数：
売上合計：
平均売上：

上記をブラウザに表示しcsvファイルとしてダウンロードしたいという感じです。
サンプルコードは下記に記載致します。

```
<?php
$datafile = 'sales.csv'; // CSV ファイル

$fh = fopen($datafile, 'r');
if ($fh) {
  flock($fh, LOCK_SH);

  $lst = array();
  while ($line = fgets($fh)) { // ファイルから一行ずつ読み込む
    $all = explode(',', chop($line)); // カンマで分割して配列に

    while (($key = array_shift($all)) && ($val = array_shift($all))) { // 配列の先頭から名前と値を取り出す
      $lst{$key} = $val; // 連想配列にセット
      $lst{$key} = mb_convert_encoding($lst{$key}, "SJIS", 'utf-8');
    }
  }

$sum = 0;
$count = 0;

foreach ($lst as $name => $sale) {
  $count += 1;
  $sum += $sale;
  $avr = $sum / $count;
}

$fileName = "report.csv";
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
readfile($fileName);


echo "社員数：".$count."<br>";
echo "売上合計：".$sum."<br>";
echo "売上平均：".$avr."<br>";

flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fh);

}
?>
```

[image: csv文字化け]

Comment: 1)どのソフトで表示してどのように文字化けするのですか？例えばスクリーンショットがあるとわかりやすいです。 2)ダウンロードさせる内容はこのプログラムでの集計とは関係ない、`report.csv` というファイルなのですか？ 3)一回のリクエストで表示とダウンロードを同時に行うことはできず、 echo している分もダウンロードさせられていませんか？

Comment: ダウンロードさせるための header() の前に echo しているのでダウンロードは行われず（Content-Type等指定しているものはブラウザまで届いてない）全てブラウザ上に表示されていると思います。で、echoはUTF-8,csvとして出力しているつもりのものはSJISなので文字化け表示となっている。

Comment: @unarist さん、コメントありがとうございます。以下回答になります。
1) スクリーンショットは上記に記載しております。2) report.csvとしてダウンロードしたい内容はブラウザに表示させる社員数・売上合計・平均売上です。3) ということはブラウザに表示させる処理とダウンロード処理を分けたほうがいいということでしょうか？（例：ボタンを押すとcsvとしてダウンロードされる）

Answer (score 1):

CSVの期待する文字コードはSJISということでよろしいでしょうか？ 元のCSVを読み込むときはwhile内でSJIS→UTF8への変換がされていると思うのですが、書き出す時に変換されておらず、UTF8のまま出力されているように見えます。
echoでの出力内容を、入力時と同じようにmb_convert_encodingでUTF8→SJISに変換してやれば解決しませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

スクリーンショットで文字化けしている冒頭部分は、UTF-8で書かれた「社員数」をSJISとして表示したものです。Windows版のExcelは `*.csv` のファイルをSJISで読み込みますが、Mac版も同様なのでしょう。

前述の文字列を表示している個所は

```
echo "社員数：".$count."<br>";
```

ですが、ここでSJISに変換することなく出力しているため、文字化けが起きています。

> report.csvとしてダウンロードしたい内容はブラウザに表示させる社員数・売上合計・平均売上です。

質問に書かれたプログラムでは `report.csv` を生成することはなく、読み取り出力しているだけですよね。なので `No such file or directory` という、指定されたファイルが見つからないというエラーが `readfile()` で起きています。

`report.csv` をサーバー側で生成してもいいですが、別に `readfile()` を使わずとも `echo` などで出力すればそのままダウンロードさせることができます。例えば、変数に含まれるデータをSJISのCSVでダウンロードさせるサンプルとして、以下のサイトなどはどうでしょうか。

[PHP で CSV ファイルをダウンロードさせる | モノリオ](http://monolio.com/memo/php/php-download-csv/)

ちなみに現在のソースコードでも `mb_convert_encoding()` が使われていますね。

```
$lst{$key} = mb_convert_encoding($lst{$key}, "SJIS", 'utf-8');
```

この書き方でUTF-8からSJISへの変換を行いますが、この `$lst{$key}` の中身は売上の数値列になります。半角英数はUTF-8でもSJISでも同じ表現になりますから、ここを変換する意味はないでしょう。

### 表示とダウンロード

ダウンロードする場合でもブラウザ上で表示する場合でも、サーバー側から送るデータは似たようなものです。 `Content-Disposition: attachment;` というHTTPヘッダを付けることで、ブラウザがファイルのダウンロードとして扱うようになるのです。

HTTPヘッダはレスポンスの先頭に一度だけ設定するものなので、一回のレスポンスで「表示」と「ダウンロード」を同時にさせることはできません。今回の場合、 `header()` の前に `echo` した分までCSVに含まれてしまっていますね。

> ブラウザに表示させる処理とダウンロード処理を分けたほうがいいということでしょうか？（例：ボタンを押すとcsvとしてダウンロードされる）

ということになります。

Answer (score 0):

mb_convert_encodingを使ってSJISにすると良いでしょうか。

以下に参考記事を紹介します。

[PHPでExcelで開いても文字化けしないCSVを出力する](http://qiita.com/ikemonn/items/f2bc4f9f834c989084ff)

Comment: $sum = 0;　の前に定義してます。ここがおかしいのでしょうか。

Comment: おっと説明不足でしたね、出力前に変換する必要がありますので、mb_convert_encodingの位置を変えましょう。

Comment: どこの位置に変えれば良いでしょうか？